# How to reduce the height of the DropDownButtonFormField so that the text inside it does not go out of the middle in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dropdownbutton, flutter-textinputfield

When I set a height for my container that is the parent of DropDownButtonFormField, I have no problem when the height is 55, but when the height is less (42) than a certain limit, the text inside it looks like this.

[image]

As it is clear in the picture, cat is no longer in the middle of the container.
this is my code:

```dart
Container(
  alignment: Alignment.center,
  width: double.infinity,
  height: 40,
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    color: Colors.white,
    border: Border.all(
      color: const Color(0xFF616161),
      width: 0.65,
    ),
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
  ),
  child: Padding(
    padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 10, 0),
    child: DropdownButtonFormField(
      enableFeedback: true,
      menuMaxHeight: 200,
      icon: Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_down_rounded),
      iconSize: 21,
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      // decoration: InputDecoration.collapsed(hintText: ''),
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        border: InputBorder.none,
        prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.location_on_rounded),
      ),
      dropdownColor: Colors.white,
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(8)),
      elevation: 2,
      // isExpanded: true,
      value: cityValue,
      onChanged: (String? newValue) {
        setState(() {
          cityValue = newValue!;
        });
      },
      items: <String>['Tehran', 'Cat', 'Tiger', 'Lion']
          .map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
        return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
          value: value,
          child: Text(
            value,
            style:
                TextStyle(fontSize: 15, color: Color(0xff707070)),
          ),
        );
      }).toList(),
    ),
  ),
),
```

The icon is in the middle but not the text.
I used Offset, but then the icon gets messed up.

Answer (score 4):

The default Icon size 24, so you need minimum height 48 to view properly. It would be better not to force it have certain height.You can remove height 40 for better UX.

Now let say you like to have fixed hight, for this case, you need to maintain padding for yourself.

```dart
decoration: InputDecoration(
  border: InputBorder.none,
  contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 6), //this one
  prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.location_on_rounded),
),
```

[image]

```dart
Container(
  alignment: Alignment.center,
  width: double.infinity,
  height: 40,
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    color: Colors.white,
    border: Border.all(
      color: const Color(0xFF616161),
      width: 0.65,
    ),
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
  ),
  child: Padding(
    padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 0),
    child: DropdownButtonFormField(
      enableFeedback: true,
      menuMaxHeight: 200,
      icon: Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_down_rounded),
      iconSize: 20,
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      // decoration: InputDecoration.collapsed(hintText: ''),
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        border: InputBorder.none,
        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 6), //this one
        prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.location_on_rounded),
      ),
      dropdownColor: Colors.white,
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(8)),
      elevation: 2,

      onChanged: (String? newValue) {},
      items: <String>['Tehran', 'Cat', 'Tiger', 'Lion']
          .map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
        return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
          value: value,
          child: Text(
            value,
            style:
                TextStyle(fontSize: 15, color: Color(0xff707070)),
          ),
        );
      }).toList(),
    ),
  ),
),
```

Answer (score 3):

A quick solution is adding a `contentPadding` to the `InputDecoration`.

```
contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 7),
```

Answer (score 2):

Try below code using [`InputDecoration`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/InputDecoration-class.html)

```
  DropdownButtonFormField(
          decoration: const InputDecoration(
            focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(4)),
              borderSide: BorderSide(width: 1, color: Colors.grey),
            ),
            contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
              horizontal: 10.0,
              vertical: 3.0,
            ),
            border: OutlineInputBorder(),
            prefixIcon: Icon(
              Icons.location_on_rounded,
              color: Colors.grey,
            ),
          ),
          dropdownColor: Colors.white,
          borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
            Radius.circular(8),
          ),
          icon: const Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_down_rounded),
          onChanged: (value) => {
            cityValue = value!,
          },
          items: <String>['Tehran', 'Cat', 'Tiger', 'Lion']
              .map(
                (e) => DropdownMenuItem(
                  value: e,
                  child: Text(e),
                ),
              )
              .toList(),
        ),
```

Your Result Screen-> [image]

Answer (score 2):

Both horizontal and vertical padding will looks nice into `InputDecoration` put this line

```
contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 7,horizontal: 10),
```